# How to remove SPACES and HYPHENS from list of names

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So im trying to write a powershell script to do 2 things, the first is to remove any last name that is AFTER the first space,

I got that with

```
$last_nospace = $_.lname -replace  '^([^ ]+ ).+$','$1'
```

than I want it to also remove any names that are hyphenated (not sure if I can do this at the same time)

```
$last_nohyphen = $_.lname -replace  '-',''
```

However it seems to give mixxed results, sometimes MULTIPLE names are the same,

Is it possible to easily say

```
Remove all additional names after the first space or hyphen?
```

Im creating AD accounts, and I want it always to be uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$last_nospace = $_.lname -replace  '\s.*$' -replace '-'
```

Comment: Thanks, that works - I have SOME names that are like "Del Toro" or "El-Pedro" that kinda of get messed up but I don think I can fix that

Answer (score 0):

I would split the last name up with spaces, then split with hyphens. After that, select the first item in the result:

```
$last_nospace = $_.lname -split '\s.*' -split '-' | Select -First 1
```